# classes and creating multiple objects in C++

Tags: c++, class

I've written a program for my C++ class and I ran into a little problem which I'm not quite sure how to solve. Some of you may be familiar with this textbook exercise as I've seen questions asked about it on the site before, but I was unable to find any simple fix.

I have to create a class which is used to store information about a pizza. I've got the program written and functional, but I need the class call to loop through a series of iterations based on the user's input. I know that this can be achieved using vectors, something we haven't hit yet in the semester, but will get to soon enough I'm sure. Is there a way to do this without vectors?

Here's the class.

```
    class Pizza
{
private:
    int type;
    int size;
    int numCheeseTopping;
    int numPepperoniTopping;
    bool cheeseTopping;    
    bool pepperoniTopping;

public:
    Pizza();
    int getType();
    int getSize();
    bool getCheese();
    bool getPepperoni();
    void setType(int t);
    void setSize(int s);
    void setCheese(bool choice, int temp);
    void setPepperoni(bool choice, int temp);

    void outputDescription();
    double computePrice();
    void outputPrice();
};
```

And the constructor.

```
Pizza::Pizza()
{   
    // Set initial class values
    type = DEEPDISH;
    size = SMALL;
    cheeseTopping = false;
    numCheeseTopping = 0;
    pepperoniTopping = false;
    numPepperoniTopping = 0;
}
```

Main is only two functions.

```
// Main function
int main()
{
    // Call global functions
    welcomeMsg();
    buildPizza();

    return 0;
}
```

I have a feeling that my problem lies in the buildPizza function, as it calls other functions as well as creating the objects. Here it is...

```
void buildPizza()
{
    char pType, pSize, tempCheese, tempPepperoni;
    int type = 0, size = 0, numCheeseTopping = 0, numPepperoniTopping = 0;

    // Ask user what size pizza they would like.
    cout << "What size pizza would you like?" << endl;
    cout << "\tS: Small" << endl;
    cout << "\tM: Medium" << endl;
    cout << "\tL: Large" << endl;
    cout << "Size: ";
    cin >> pSize;

    // Determine which size the user input and convert the 
    // result.
    switch (pSize)
    {
    case 'S':
    case 's':
        size = SMALL;
        break;
    case 'M':
    case 'm':
        size = MEDIUM;
        break;
    case 'L':
    case 'l':
        size = LARGE;
        break;
    }

    // Ask the user which type of pizza they would like.
    cout << endl << "What type pizza would you like?" << endl;
    cout << "\tD: Deepdish" << endl;
    cout << "\tH: Hand-Tossed" << endl;
    cout << "\tP: Pan" << endl;
    cout << "Type: ";
    cin >> pType;

    // Determine which type the user input and convert the
    // result.
    switch (pType)
    {
    case 'D':
    case 'd':
        type = DEEPDISH;
        break;
    case 'H':
    case 'h':
        type = HANDTOSSED;
        break;
    case 'P':
    case 'p':
        type = PAN;
        break;
    }

    // Call Pizza Class.
    Pizza myPizza;

    // Call Pizza Class functions.
    myPizza.setSize(size);
    myPizza.setType(type);

    // Ask user whether they want cheese or not.
    cout << endl << "Would you like cheese (y/n)? ";
    cin >> tempCheese;

    // If so call setCheese.
    if (tempCheese == 'Y' || tempCheese == 'y')
    {
        cout << "How many cheese toppings would you like? ";
        cin >> numCheeseTopping;
        myPizza.setCheese(true, numCheeseTopping);
    }

    // Ask user whether they want pepperoni or not.
    cout << endl << "Would you like pepperoni (y/n)? ";
    cin >> tempPepperoni;

    // If so call setPepperoni.
    if (tempPepperoni == 'Y' || tempPepperoni == 'y')
    {
        cout << "How many pepperoni toppings would you like? ";
        cin >> numPepperoniTopping;
        myPizza.setPepperoni(true, numPepperoniTopping);
    }

    // Call outputDescription to give user an overview
    // of their order.
    cout << endl << endl;
    myPizza.outputDescription();
    cout << endl;

    // Compute the cost of the pizza and display it.
    myPizza.outputPrice();
}
```

Basically, I'd like the program to ask the user how many pizzas they would like to evaluate, create that many class iterations, then cycle through 'building' or 'ordering' each pizza, then display a total and return 0.

As I look at the code now I can take the last two function calls out of buildPizza and move the calls into main, but this will not solve my problem. Only an oversight I literally just noticed within the program.

Is there an easy way to create, say, 200 new objects all at once at runtime. Each one with a different name? Should I just pick a number to evaluate and force the user to enter information for that many objects? Right now, the program evaluates one pizza and quits.

I'd like something like this to happen:

1. User asks program to create a 5 pizza order.
2. Program creates 5 pizza objects.
3. Program iterates through each object getting and setting information for each one.
4. Program displays some stuff and returns 0.

Is this possible with my code, or do I need to consider a rewrite? Any guidance the community can give me will be immensely helpful. 
Thanks.

Kyle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you cnanot use arrays or vectors, a simple for would suffice.

```
auto nrPizzas = getNumberOfPizzasFromUserInput();
for(int i = 0; i < nrPizzas; i++) {
    auto pizza = Pizza{};
    // do your stuff here.
    output to the screen here();
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your suggestion. I will try it tonight and post an update. This looks like it is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You can prompt for the number of pizzas user want and then create a dynamic array of that much pizzas and then iterate through their build function or else you can make a linked-list with struct type of pizza and then rewrite the main logic. Second approach is advised if you do not want to prompt that how many pizza's the user wants to order.